# Inner join on two tables which are not mapped using HQL

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have table A and table b having no relationship. But table A, table B mapped with entity, and there's no relationship between the entities. 
Assume tables are mapped as below.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tableA")
public class TableA

@Entity
@Table(name = "tableB")
public class TableB
```

### table A

ida,
ref_no,
schema,
type

### table B

idb,
accountno,
sechema,
type

I need to get the "accountno" from tableB for the given "ref_no" which having same "sechema" and "type". I can get the "accountno" using the below native SQL query in my repository class which implements CrudRepository.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT b.accountno FROM DB.tableA as a INNER JOIN DB.tableB as b ON b.sechema = a.sechema AND b.type = a.type WHERE a.ref_no= ?1", nativeQuery = true)
Integer findByRefNo(String refNo);
```

Could someone help me to overcome this problem, because using native query, I need to change if DB name different.

I have tried with below but it gave me errors.

```
@Query(value = select b.accountno from TableA a join TableB b where b.sechema = a.sechema and b.type = a.type and (:refNo is null or a.refNo = :refNo)")
Integer findByRefNo(@Param("refNo") String refNo);
```

Comment: If something you tried results in an exception, please include the exception (the complete call stack) in the question. It often helps to find a suitable answer and also helps others find the question if they have a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Hibernate 5.1+ the query will be almost the same in HQL:

```
@Query("select b.accountno from TableA a join TableB b on b.sechema = a.sechema and b.type = a.type where a.ref_no= ?1")
Integer findByRefNo(String refNo);
```

More info: [1](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-explicit-join-jpql-on-example), [2](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-join-unrelated-entities-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)

Comment: Thx Cerp0. I'll try it and let you know.